# CPU utilization usage check in EC2 for the past time usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, cpu, utilization

In AWS My CPU Utilization goes from 2% to 90% for 10 minutes how to get the usage details for the past usage time in AWS EC2 instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the cpu utilization of the instance, we need to have the `ID of the instance`. We can get the instance ID using the AWS Management Console or the `describe-instances` command.

By default, basic monitoring is enabled, but we can enable detailed monitoring for the Ec2 instance.

Once we have the instance Id, we can get the cpu stats by using the command

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --metric-name CPUUtilization  --period 3600 \
--statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-EC2_INSTANCE_ID \
--start-time 2022-10-18T23:18:00 --end-time 2022-10-19T23:18:00
```

Alternatively, we can view the graphs on CloudWatch. Please refer to the following [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/US_SingleMetricPerInstance.html) for complete details.